# navigation drawer in dialog, multiple v-content?

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm just checking out vuetify and I would like to add a dialog that contains a v-navigation-drawer.

How do I need to structure the layout inside the dialog to achieve the same effect in the dialog like with a v-navigation-drawer ( menu on the left, content on the right ).

thats my markup right now:

```
v-app
  v-dialog
    v-toolbar
    v-navigation-drawer
      v-list
        .. menuitems
    v-content
      (content here is under the left menu not on the right side as on my screenshot)
  v-content
    v-container
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjdH0.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the cleanest solution, but it could be something like this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
      return {
        dialog: null,
        notifications: false,
        sound: true,
        widgets: false
      }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons" />

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-btn primary dark v-on:click.stop="dialog = true">Open Dialog</v-btn>
    <v-dialog v-model="dialog"  transition="dialog-bottom-transition" width="80%" fullscreen hide-overlay >
      <v-card>
        <v-toolbar dark class="primary">
          <v-btn icon @click.native="dialog = false" dark>
            <v-icon>close</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
          <v-toolbar-title>Settings</v-toolbar-title>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-toolbar-items>
            <v-btn dark flat @click.native="dialog = false">Save</v-btn>
          </v-toolbar-items>
        </v-toolbar>
         <v-navigation-drawer
                                        permanent
                                        absolute
                                        left
                                        width="250"
                                        class='mt-5'
                                        height=""

                                >
                                    <v-list light one-line class="grey pa-1">
                                        <v-list-tile>
                                            <v-list-tile-content>
                                                <v-list-tile-title class="white--text subheading">
                                                    HEADER
                                                </v-list-tile-title>
                                            </v-list-tile-content>
                                        </v-list-tile>
                                    </v-list>
                                    <v-list class="pt-0" dense>
                                        <v-divider></v-divider>
                                        <v-list-tile >
                                              Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
                                        </v-list-tile>
                                    </v-list>
                                </v-navigation-drawer>
          <v-flex class="text-xs-center">
                <h3 class="headline mb-0">Kangaroo Valley Safari</h3>
                <div>Located two hours south of Sydney in the <br>Southern Highlands of New South Wales, ...</div>
          </v-flex>
 
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </v-app>
</div>
```